# How to remove monitor flickering noise from an image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to remove a noise from a photo of a monitor screen. Here's the source photo:

[image]

I've tried some different approaches, so the current version of my code is as follows:

```
clr_img = cv2.imread("D:\Noisy.jpg", 1) 
gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(clr_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
gray_img = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(gray_img, h=11)
binary_image = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray_img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 91, 12)
```

Here's the result:

[image]

Is it possible to get rid of this kind of the noise?

Comment: That's not monitor flickering, it's moire from the dot pattern of the display.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to apply a smoothing operation before adaptive thresholding. A simple blur should help to reduce the noise. Any of these should work: Simple average blur ([`cv2.blur`](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_filtering/py_filtering.html#averaging)), Gaussian blur ([`cv2.GaussianBlur`](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_filtering/py_filtering.html#gaussian-filtering)), or Median blur ([`cv2.medianBlur`](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_filtering/py_filtering.html#median-filtering)). Here's the result using a `(7,7)` Gaussian blur:

[image]

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (7,7), 0)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,51,9)
result = 255 - thresh

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey()
```